# Why use buttons instead of Card .clickable in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

While developing apps in imperative approach using XML, it made perfect sense to use Buttons. However since in Jetpack Compose we can make pretty much everything clickable (for example Card with .clickable property), what is the point of using Buttons?

Comment: Also in XML everything can be clickable. Wha is the point of using Button in xml?

Comment: A card and a button are not the same visually.

Answer (score 3):

There's no difference. The `Button` Composable is nothing more than a `Surface` with a `Box` in it which has a `Modifier.Clickable` set to it.

It's just a premade Composable which has the necessary functions like `onClick` ready for you so you don't need to implement them yourself.

Comment: Cards and Buttons have different features. The clickable interface is only a feature. It is not correct to say *"there is no difference"*.